# Boot utilities for 3 TB hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, gpt, disk-utility

What hard disk/partitioning/GPT/cloning/etc. utilities are there to have on a bootable USB drive or CD/DVD, that can work with NTFS and other file systems, on hard drives greater than 2.1 TB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some advice about system utilities that support GPT in the article [Make the most of large drives with GPT and Linux](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gpt/).